# Reponsive website partially based on device instead of screen resolution

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, media-queries, user-agent

I've got my responsive website done with breakpoints setted up with @media queries. I've got couple of basic breakpoints

1. min-width: 1600px - for TVs and bigger resolution screens (that just center the whole page and make white margins on sides, nothing too significant)
2. max-width: 1024px - for tablets, there are many changes, especially because tablets has of corse touch screen, which desktops usually haven't. At all it looks pretty different.
3. max-width: 600px - for smarphones, there is also a lot of changes based especcialy on narrowing the content from two or four colums into one.

Now I found that might be a problem, because there are nowdays tablets which acts in the browser, as they have resolution width for example 1280px, but there are also still computers with width of monitor 1280px too, even smaller, so I can't change the breakpoint value for this.

I of course don't want the desktop version on tablet and tablet version on comuter, becase they're created not as much for resolution but more for the platform.

I know that there are things called user agents like WURFL, which seems to be perfect for this. But is there any way how to connect this value from WURFL (tablet, desktop, smartpohne...) with css @media queries.

For example detect in WURFL that the device is tablet and change the breakpoint value in CSS file, so it shows the tablet version, instead of desktop version? Or is there any other way with similar result as this theoretical solution?

Comment: Why not give users the choice of which interface they use?

Comment: The point of responsive design is that you do not design for devices. What you are describing is not really responsive design. You should stop testing for devices and just use media queries to make sure the site looks good at all dimensions.

Comment: @RobG I'm not sure what you mean with it. If I buy tablet with bigger resolution, similar as on desktop, I would still like to have the tablet version there, which is higher and has bigger links and buttons and is more comfortable to control and read for tablet user.

Comment: You should control that with a media query, not by testing resolutions.

Comment: @moss But what if I focus not just for it to look good, but also for the functionality for different platforms. The tablet user has only touch screen, otherwise desktop user has keybord and mouse to control the web. That is two differents thinks. In tablet version you have for example completly different menu, as on desktop. It's just made to be more comfortable on touchscreen.

Comment: All sizes of your site should be functional for both mouse and touch. There are touch screens of all sizes and some devices have both touch and a mouse.

Comment: They are functional for both of corse. But if you have a tablet u just have usually only thouch screen, I'm not saying all the time but usually. When you have computer, you usually work with mouse, again not all the time. You can have of corse a touch screen on desktop. But they're just different devices, so why the design couldn't be based on type of device, insted of resolution? Of corse that you can have functional dekstop version on tablet, but wouldn't it be better to have there this tablet version, which just fits little bit better in tablet device.

Comment: Currently media queries don’t cover stuff like _“is main input method touch or mouse?”_ … I think you’re better off here with a small piece of JS that figures this out, and adds a class to the html element based on this, that your CSS rules can refer to.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need identify the device, just use the right media queries.

```
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

jQuery code to detect mobile devices

http://www.webtrainingcentre.com/jquery/scripts/jquery-code-to-detect-mobile-devices/

Comment: That's not really what I was asking for. In my question I've mentioned that I know about WURFL.js which tells me if it is tablet or mobile or anything. I need more know how to connect it somehow with CSS media queries.